# DateTime::createFromFormat - php format issue

Tags: php, format, timestamp

PHP - DateTime::createFromFormat — Returns new DateTime object formatted according to the specified format

this works:

```
$var = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd','20100809')->getTimestamp();
```

but this fails with

> Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object

```
$var = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:M:S','2010/08/09 07:47:00')->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 18):

In the case at hand, the `M:S` portion is wrong. It needs to be `i:s`. See the [manual on date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

However, this highlights a deeper conceptual problem: An incorrect input in either parameter will lead to a fatal error, which is bad behaviour for an application in production.

From the manual on [`createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

> Returns a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure.

When the call fails to build a date from your input, no object is returned.

To avoid fatal errors on incorrect inputs, you would (sadly, as this breaks the nice chaining) have to check for success first:

```
 $var = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:M:S','2010/08/09 07:47:00');

 if ($var instanceof DateTime)
  echo $var->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Not `m:s`; `i:s`. `m` is for moth.

Answer (score 11):

It should be

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i:s','2010/08/09 07:47:00')->getTimestamp()
                                    ^ ^
```

See [`date`](http://php.net/date) for the format used.

You could also use `strtotime` in this circumstance. This would give the same result:

```
strtotime('2010/08/09 07:47:00')
```

Another way:

```
date_create('2010/08/09 07:47:00')->getTimestamp()
```

Note that `DateTime::createFromFormat` returns `FALSE` on error. You can fetch the errors with `DateTime::getLastErrors()`:

```
<?php
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:M:S','2010/08/09 07:47:00');
var_dump($d);
var_dump(DateTime::getLastErrors());
```

would give:

```
bool(false)
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(3)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [14]=>
    string(13) "Trailing data"
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for DateTime::getLastErrors(), really useful ..

Answer (score 0):

Use **s** in place of **S** 
and **m** in place of **M**

- s - Seconds, with leading zeros
- S - English ordinal suffix for the
  day of the month, 2 characters like
  st, nd, rd or th

and

- m - Numeric representation of a
  month, with leading zeros
- M - short textual representation of a
  month, three letters like Jan through
  Dec

Answer (score 0):

H:M:S
M is month short name and S is ordinal (st, nd,rd,th) day of month
try H:i:s