# How to parse date string to dateTime in php?

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

I have a date string in this format "2014-12-01 16:00:02,153". How do I parse this to a datetime format for mysql?

I am using laravel and Carbon. My code is `Carbon::parse("2014-12-01 16:00:02,153");`

but get an error that reads `DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2014-12-01 16:00:02,153) at position 20 (1): Unexpected character`

Comment: the comma is the problem i believe, you should trim it and anything after that and it should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime::createFromFormat - php format issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467315/datetimecreatefromformat-php-format-issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the createFromFormat method from the DateTime object :

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s,u', "2014-12-01 16:00:02,153");
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Welcome. Also a great idea +1 for this!

Answer (score 2):

PHP is confused by the time format you are handing over.

```
new DateTime("2014-12-01 16:00:02,153"); // fails

strtotime("2014-12-01 16:00:02,153"); // fails
```

This is because of the unexpected part with the comma at the end. Where are you getting this strange timestamp with comma seperated milliseconds from? It is unusual.

As you are asking for datetime which usually does not need any milliseconds you can do the following:

```
$timeparts = explode(",","2014-12-01 16:00:02,153");

Carbon::parse($timeparts[0]); // should work
```

`$timeparts[1]` is the milliseconds then.

If you want to be more precise you can round the milliseconds:

```
if(intval($timeparts[1]) >= 500) {
   // time +1 second
}
```

... or you treat the milliseconds seperatly if you need em. Add them to the generated timestamp later and check the docs of Carbon.