# Unable to figure out the reason of failure of DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: php, datetime

I've got this code snippet written by another dev

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(TRUE));
$dateMicro = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
```

It's throwing this error:

> Error: Call to a member function format() on bool

I guess which could mean createFromFormat returned false but I can't figure out why it did that.

What could be the cause of this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTime::createFromFormat - php format issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467315/datetimecreatefromformat-php-format-issue)

Comment: cannot reproduce the error. or any error.

Comment: @pavel Thanks for suggesting that but I've already checked it and it doesn't help

Comment: @SalmanA this happened in a particular use case, even I can't reproduce it so I'm trying to find what could be a possible cause of triggering this error

Comment: Related: [Can the PHP function microtime return an integer...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46774848/562359)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.u` format suggests that the input string contains a `.` followed by (up to six) digits. Your code will fail when the float returned by `microtime(true)` has 0 or more than 6 digits after decimal.

You can test it with following script:

```
while (true) {
        $time = microtime(true);
        // potential fix
        // $time = sprintf('%.6f', microtime(true));
        echo $time , "\n";
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', $time);
        $dateMicro = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
}
```

Output

```
...
1642510930.9999
1642510930.9999
1642510930.9999
1642510930.9999
1642510930.9999
1642510930.9999
1642510931
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on bool in .../test.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in .../test.php on line 7
```

Comment: That is what I was going to say.

Answer (score 0):

Problem recognized. Created loop:

```php
        while(true) {
            $microTime = microtime(true);
            if ($now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', $microTime)) {
                break;
            }
            echo var_dump(DateTime::getLastErrors()) . PHP_EOL .
                '  $microTime: ' . $microTime
            );
        }
```

And got:

```
 [
    'warning_count' => 0
    'warnings' => []
    'error_count' => 1
    'errors' => [
        10 => 'Data missing'
    ]
]
  $microTime: 1706851023
```

If microtime(true) get 1642510930.000, it return string "1642510930".

Solution:

```
$microTime = microtime(true);
if (strlen($microTime) === 10) {
    $microTime .= '.000000';
}
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', $microTime);
```